# Play framework 2.x (Scala) Navigation menu - Best practice to get some data from db on every request

Tags: scala, playframework

I've a question....I'm structuring a website with Play 2.7 (Scala). 
I'm building something like a cms ..where you can create Page , Events, post comments and so on...I'm stuck building a navigation menu that should be created from some data stored in my db tables (categories).

My problem is that this "data" should be extracted on every request (home page, events page, posts page) and I'm not sure about the best approach of doing this. I was thinking about those 3 solutions:

1. Inject my category service on each controller and pass for every action the navigation menu data on the view
2. Create a filter that before each controller will call the service retrieve the data and pass it through the request eventually in my template get data from "request object"
3. (not sure if possible) create a Module or Helper that can be used directly on template something like @GiveMeTheMenu() that return Seq[Category]

What do you think? any advice will be great!! thank you all.

Comment: Better approach is to create an API.

Comment: Do you mean a REST API? for the backend data and something like AngularJS for client side?

Comment: Yes. Just a little spice, like Secure Action on your API to make it awesome :)

Comment: To control API access and request

Answer (score 1):

Something like this @LucatT. Hope it helps.

`routes`

```
GET     /menu                  controllers.HomeController.giveMeTheMenu()
```

`HomeController.scala`

```
def giveMeTheMenu() =  SecureUserAction.async { implicit request =>
  // Codes here and fetch data from DB..
}
```

Comment: Thanks ...I was thinking at something different but yes this could be a valid approach. I'm wondering if could be better to create all the application based on REST api..maybe with a JWT authentication on top using also Akka {http and actors} and the JsonSpraySupport. Thank you for your answer.